# Domain availability checks through a REST API

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Note: i'm not looking for a domain availability webservice! Now that we got that out of the way ...

How would I architect a system that both allow us to retrieve resources from our domain portfolio through our REST API and also perform domain availability checks in the same API? Is it a good idea to use the same URI for both cases or should I use a different resource for this?

For example:

If I want information on example.com (which is a domain in our portfolio) I would `GET /domains/example.com/` to retrieve our information on it (registration info like nameservers, contacts, etc ... but also internal information like our client record, invoice number, etc ...) .

If I would want to get the domain availability for example.org (which is not registered with us so not in our portfolio) I would also call `GET /domains/example.org/` which then would return wether or not the domain is available.

In short: is it a good idea to use the same URI for these two things (which basically both return info on a domain?) or should I use a different resource for this? `/domainregistration/example.com/` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of a REST API is to provide an abstraction of implementation details and logic of, in your case, domain information. Under this point of view the abstraction could fit because you retrieve domain information from domains in your portfolio and from domains not in your portfolio.

But there is also some difference in retrieving domain information, for example retrieving domain information about domains not in your portfolio is slow, or at least slower than retrieving information for domains in your portfolio. Another difference is that for REST APIs often some bulk capabilities for retrieving more than one resource information are provided like this `GET /domains/example.com,anotherexample.com,localhost.com/`. You will/might not want such functionality to be accessible when retrieving information about domains that are not in your portfolio.

Another reason why you might split the resources is that you could implement a call that retrieves all information about domains in your portfolio:

```
GET /domains/
```

This request could obviously only return information about domains in your portfolio, so your abstraction would break in that case.

When you model your REST API to retrieve domain availability I would suggest to use a resource like

```
PUT /availabilities/example.com
```

to create a domain availability check. This resource could create a sub resource `example.com` that can be then used to retrieve information about this availability check, or used to cache domain availability check results via:

```
GET /availabilities/example.com
```

Taking all these arguments together I'd favor splitting resources, because:

- In case an API user is interested in detailed domain information of domains in your portfolio the API user could check the `/domains` resource
- To get information if a domain is in your portfolio the user would also use the `/domains/example.com` resource
- API users that are only interested in a domain availability check can use the `availabilities` resource to perform this check.

Comment: Very good and clear answer, but I just have one question, why would you need to do a PUT request to create the resource first if a GET request does all I need, regardless of a PUT request being done in advance?

Comment: The PUT request is just a possibility to model asynchronous requests, you could PUT/POST a domain availability request that would create a resource that can be queried if the request is finished or not. A GET will work perfectly if you just return a synchronous availability result